# ClassCastException for Time Picker value + Local Notification

Tags: codenameone

The following code give me a **java.lang.ClassCastException**

```
long time=timePicker.getDate().getTime();
Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(notification, time, LocalNotification.REPEAT_DAY);
```

When i execute this code, i have the following error:

**java.lang.ClassCastException - java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date**

**getTime()** returns long and not int so the code is correct. What is the cause of this issue?

timePicker variable is a Picker

```
timePicker=new Picker();
timePicker .setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time picker doesn't return a date. You should replace your code with:

```
int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60000;
int time=timePicker.getTime();
Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(notification, time * 60000 + System.currrentTimeMillis() / DAY * DAY, LocalNotification.REPEAT_DAY);
```

In this case time will be seconds since midnight. The reason is that time picker doesn't include the date portion or the timezone. `Date` is very fragile/confusing when it comes to those two things so we provide a more consistent result with that approach. This is also true for duration pickers.

Comment: Hi Shai, Your code does not work too. When i use it, i have the following exception; `Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Cannot schedule a notification to a past time`

Comment: I answered the mistake about the picker, I revised the answer to cover the parts you should have changed for the rest of the code

Comment: Shai, your code does not work. With your code, the notification does not trigger on the selected time that i schedule. Nothing happen when the time that i choose comes.

Comment: I typed `%` instead of `/` which I corrected now... I would suggest debugging and inspecting the values of variables to spot mistakes like that

Comment: Shai, there is another issue in your code. You wrote 1000 instead of 60000. I made the change and it works well now. This is because the value of time here is in minutes, not in seconds. You assumed it was in seconds and that's why you multiplied it by 1000 to get its value in milliseconds. It should be multiplied by 60000 to have the value in milliseconds. The final code is:
`Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(notification, time * 60000 + System.currrentTimeMillis() / DAY * DAY, LocalNotification.REPEAT_DAY);`
My problem is now solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes I forgot. I fixed the answer. FYI you should accept correct answers by clicking the `V` mark next to them